# Excel Breaking Links between sheets/workbooks stored on OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, sharepoint

I use Excel for work and we recently moved over to OneDrive for business and SharePoint. The Onedrive is mapped as a drive and I only use Excel as a local app, i.e No Excel online.

When I create a link between 2 sheets in separate workbooks they break after saving.

Is there a work around for this? It seems like there is a problem with it.

Thank you.

Extra info:

Here is the original path:

='[NEW! Crew Utilization Hours (2019).xlsm]Chart Info'!$C$114

and here is the path after saving the file and re-openning:

='https://******.sharepoint.com/Users/*****/******/******** - *******/[NEW! Crew Utilization Hours (2019).xlsm]Chart Info'!$C$114

(note the *** are removed possible sensitive information)

The path restructures itself, not in it's self an issue for me....if it worked! That's the problem, whenever I re-open after saving the links no longer update etc etc and Excel fires warnings off at me to that point.

Also this is Excel 2016 that I am working with.

UPDATE:

I have been playing around with 2 seperate workbook test files, contained in seperate folders on the same OneDrive.

In the test files I have noticed that the problem does not happen when a different 'Path' is used for example:

=SERIES(,'https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/*********/Shared Documents/******/MANAGER/Test 1/[Test 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$3:$C$3,'https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/Shared Documents/******/MANAGER/Test 1/[Test 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$6:$C$6,3)

That path works! no errors and no cant update.

However I don't seem to have any control over how that path is created as opposed to the other non working path, sometimes the first path is created by excel and sometimes it is this type created which works, or is it something I am unwittingly doing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Sorry, I was on the understanding that this particular issue is an issue specific to OneDrive and Excel as opposed to corporate IT network structure. If the IT department had a fix I wouldn't of been asking if anyone else has had an issue such as this and any possible solution.